# AS3 Juming/Gravity issue

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, gravity

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make the character stop jumping.

For example, when I constantly hit space it keeps jumping and jumping. When I press space I want it to jump and while the MC is jumping I want to disable the space button (or if possible could you also tell me how to disable `MouseEvents`) so that while in the air the MC can only jump once.

```
var gravity = 0.8;
var floor = 251;
player.y = floor;
player.speedY = 0;
player.impulsion = 10;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    player.speedY += gravity;
    player.y += player.speedY;
    if(player.y > floor) {
        player.speedY = 0;
        player.y = floor

    }

}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, space);
function space(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        player.speedY = -player.impulsion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just have a Boolean variable like "`onFloor`" which is set to true when the layer lands, and set to false when they jump. Then only let them jump if they are `onFloor`. So here I've set it to true inside your `if(player.y > floor)`, and false after `if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE && onFloor)`:

```
var gravity = 0.8;
var floor = 251;
var onFloor:Boolean = false;

player.y = floor;
player.speedY = 0;
player.impulsion = 10;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    player.speedY += gravity;
    player.y += player.speedY;
    if(player.y > floor) {
        player.speedY = 0;
        player.y = floor;
        onFloor = true;
    }

}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, space);
function space(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE && onFloor) {
        player.speedY = -player.impulsion;
        onFloor = false;
    }
}
```